# how to set select value after redirecting in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and I was trying to set the value of select to the value returned from my controller. I cannot figure out why it won't change the value

**show.blade.php**

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
    <form action="{{ action('ReportController@show', ['id' => 'month']) }}" class="month-form" method="GET">
        <select name="month" id="month" class="custom-select form-input month-select">
            <option value="01">January</option>
            <option value="02">February</option>
            <option value="03">March</option>
            <option value="04">April</option>
            <option value="05">May</option>
            <option value="06">June</option>
            <option value="07">July</option>
            <option value="08">August</option>
            <option value="09">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">Generate Report</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**controller**
function show ()

```
$month_number = request('month');
$month_name = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month_number, 1));
return view('reports.show', compact('month_number', 'month_name'));
```

[This is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9db2y.png)
When I click the generate button, it goes back to this page and the value would be the one I selected from before. So, if I select May then the generate button, the new page would be May within the select instead of the  default value.

edit: I also tried using jQuery but it would only make my form blank and not give it any value at all

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var month = @json($month_name ?? '');
   $('#month').val(month);
});
```

Comment: is `month`  variable exists in url after redirecting ? and are you coming back to this page again after redirecting but with `$month_name` variable ?

Comment: yes month variable exists in the url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000//monthly-reports/month?month=05". I can get the data with console.log() but cannot change the select value

Comment: I am posting answer it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If I understand your problem clearly, then I think you want something like this**

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
<form action="{{ action('ReportController@show', ['id' => 'month']) }}" class="month-form" method="GET">
    <select name="month" id="month" class="custom-select form-input month-select">
        <option value="01" @isset($month_number) {{ $month_number == 01 ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>January</option>
        <option value="02" @isset($month_number) {{ $month_number == 02 ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>February</option>
        <option value="03" @isset($month_number) {{ $month_number == 03 ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>March</option>
        <option value="04" @isset($month_number) {{ $month_number == 04 ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>April</option>
        <option value="05" @isset($month_number) {{ $month_number == 05 ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>May</option>
        <option value="06" @isset($month_number) {{ $month_number == 06 ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>June</option>
        <option value="07" @isset($month_number) {{ $month_number == 07 ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>July</option>
        <option value="08" @isset($month_number) {{ $month_number == 08 ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>August</option>
        <option value="09" @isset($month_number) {{ $month_number == 09 ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>September</option>
        <option value="10" @isset($month_number) {{ $month_number == 10 ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>October</option>
        <option value="11" @isset($month_number) {{ $month_number == 11 ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>November</option>
        <option value="12" @isset($month_number) {{ $month_number == 12 ? 'selected' : '' }} @endisset>December</option>
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Generate Report</button>
</form>
```

If it doesn't work then try to change `01` to `"01"` and so on...